# simplexml_load_string() != simplexml_import_dom()?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

If I load an HTML page using `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile()` then pass it to `simplexml_import_dom()` everything is fine, however, if I using `$dom->saveHTML()` to get a string representation from the `DOMDocument` then use `simplexml_load_string()`, I get nothing. Actually, if I use a very simple page it will work, but as soon as there is anything more complex, it fails without any errors in the PHP log file.

Can anyone shed light on this?

Is it something to do with HTML not being parsable XML?

I am trying to strip out CR's and newlines from the formatted HTML text before using the contents as they have nothing to do with the content but get inserted into the `SimpleXMLElement` object, which is rather tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Is it something to do with HTML not being parsable XML?`

YES! HTML is a far less strict syntax so `simplexml_load_string` will not work with it by itself. This is because `simplexml` is simple and HTML is convoluted. On the other hand, DOMDocument is designed to be able to read the convoluted HTML structure, which means that since it can make sense of HTML and `simplexml` can make sense of it, you can bridge the proverbial gap there.

```
<!-- Valid HTML but not valid XML -->
<ul>
    <li>foo
    <li>bar
</ul>
```

Comment: Kinda makes you want to scream.

Comment: Even with `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">` (and versions above) this wouldn't be valid. Just so it gets interpreted by browsers doesn't make it valid html.

Comment: @Yoshi Got rid of the `<i>`. Pulled an old example. Anyway, the `<li>` part is still more than common, and I've seen it used by Google.

Comment: So the answer is really to iterate through each SimpleXMLElement element and delete any text nodes with superfluous white space?

Comment: @cwallenpoole ok, removed my downvote. But it's still ugly as hell! ;)

Comment: As a side note, is it just me, or is it a bit short sighted that document formatting gets mixed up with document content here? I guess it's an inherent drawback in HTML...

Comment: @Yoshi Gives me nightmares. Part of me cringes every time I even think about how that is valid.

Answer (score 0):

HTML may or may not be valid XML. when you use loadHTMLFile it doesnt necessarily have to be well formed xml because the DOM is an HTML one so different rules, but when you pass a string to SimpleXML it must indeed be well formed.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correclty and you simply want no whitespace in your output, then there is no need to use `simplexml` here.

Use: [DOMDocument::preservewhitespace](http://php.net/manual/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.preservewhitespace)
like:

```
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
```

before `saveHTML` and you're set.

Comment: Well, not quite. I need to use 'simplexml' to iterate through the contents. I guess I could use preserveWhiteSpace, then save the contents to a file and then reload it, but I think in the long run I'll need to solve this programatically.